# Date.UTC() gets value null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

From Server I get Date in UTC format like ,

```
2016-04-13T02:37:13.211316121-04:00
```

When I use this to display using `new Date(data.Created_at)` I get 7 min time difference. Like as I am displaying my date in format {{my_date | date: 'h:mm a'}}, insted showing `12:05 PM`, it dispalys `11:58 AM`. So I tried this,

```
data.Created_at = new Date(Date.UTC(data.Created_at))
```

which returns `null` value. Is there any problem in my code? How should I get perfect date?

Answer (score 1):

If you check syntax of `Date.UTC`,

> Date.UTC(year, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]])

It expects value in different variables and not in date string. You can split it and manually parse it.

You can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnxvsdLs/)

```js
var d = "2016-04-13T02:37:13.211316121-04:00";
var date_arr = d.split(/[-|T|\.|:]/);
var o = new Date(Date.UTC(date_arr[0], date_arr[1], date_arr[2], date_arr[3], date_arr[4], date_arr[5]));
console.log(date_arr, o);
```

Also, it gives me `8:07 AM`, considering the time is `2:37` and my timezone is `+5:30`.

Comment: I tried with your code. I got '2016-04-13T04:44:56.438972462-04:00' this time now... where my current time is 2:22 PM .. where your code returns me 10:14 AM

Comment: That is because, as I have mentioned, it will create date based on local timezone. Why are you expecting a UTC date with time `2:37`, to show `11:58` when your timezone is somewhere near `5:30`?

Comment: You are right. But what I am saying is, i have created that request at 2:22 PM.. where that UTC date on converting to local time returns 10:14 AM. It should be near 2:22PM

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

`Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,millisec)`

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is invalid way to handle date. You can use this code

```
new Date('2016-04-13T02:37:13.211316121-04:00').toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var created_at = new Date(createdAt);

var created_at_date = (created_at.getUTCMonth()+1) + "/" + created_at.getUTCDate() + "/" + created_at.getUTCFullYear() + "/" + created_at.getHours() + ":" 
+ created_at.getMinutes() + ":" + created_at.getSeconds();
```

Hope this will work for you!!!

Comment: No issue about date.. I need accurate time.